# Highcharts graph not displaying in Django template html

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I am making a website using Django/python/sqlite3. I am also using the ebay-python-sdk to query ebay database and get back information based off of keywords. I am trying to convert the timestamp into milliseconds and pass those values into a Highcharts x-axis, and the final sell price of the item to the y-axis. The graph is not displaying in the Django template (called 'graphs.html'). My code is below:

display_graphs/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
import xmltodict
from json import loads, dumps
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from django.http import HttpResponse

content_df = pd.DataFrame()

def display_the_graphs(request):
    keywords = request.POST.get('search')
    api = finding(appid='JohnHein-homepage-PRD-392e94856-07aba7fe', config_file=None, siteid='EBAY-US')
    api_request = {'keywords':keywords, 'itemFilter':[{'name':'SoldItemsOnly', 'value':True},]}
    response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', api_request)
    content = response.content
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(content)
    content_dict = to_dict(xml_dict)
    count = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['@count']
    item_dict = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['item']
    print('count:', count)
    content_df = extract_values(item_dict)
    x_values = content_df['endPrice'].tolist()
    y_values_b = content_df['endTime'].tolist()
    y_values = convert_datetime(y_values_b)
    context = {
        'response': content_df.to_html(),
        'content_df': content_df,
        'x_v': x_values,
        'y_v': y_values
    }
    return render(request, 'display_graphs/graphs.html', context)
'''
def get_time_graph(request):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title('Scatter plot of prices over time')
    ax.set_xlabel('dates')
    ax.set_ylabel('sell prices')
    ax.scatter(content_df.endDate.values, content_df.endPrice.values, s=10, label='sell prices over time')
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    context = {'first_graph':response}
    return render(request, 'display_graphs/graphs.html', context)
'''
def to_dict(input_ordered_dict):
    return loads(dumps(input_ordered_dict))

def extract_values(temp_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['itemId','title','endPrice','location','endTime'])
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []
    f = []
    #print('\ntype of data:\n', type(temp_dict))
    length = len(temp_dict)
    print('\nlength:\n', length)
    for index in range(length):
        for key, value in temp_dict[index].items():
            print('temp_dict[index][key]:', key)
            if key == 'itemId':
                a.append(value)
            if key == 'title':
                b.append(value)
            if key == 'sellingStatus':
                c.append(temp_dict[index]['sellingStatus']['currentPrice']['#text'])
            if key == 'location':
                d.append(value)
            if key == 'listingInfo':
                f.append(temp_dict[index]['listingInfo']['endTime'])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'itemId':pd.Series(a),'title':pd.Series(b),'endPrice':pd.Series(c),'location':pd.Series(d),'endTime':pd.Series(f)})  
    #print('\ndf:\n', df)
    #print('\narray a:\n', a)
    #print('\narray b:\n', b)
    #print('\narray c:\n', c)
    #print('\narray d:\n', d)
    #print('\narray f:\n', f)
    df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endTime']) # datetime ISO 8601 format ---> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +HH:MM (NOTE: '+HH:MM' is UTC offset)
    df['endTimeOfDay'],df['endDate'] = df['endTime'].apply(lambda x:x.time()),df['endTime'].apply(lambda x:x.date())
    return df

def convert_datetime(arr):
    arr2 = []
    for i in arr:
        dateobj = str(i)
        dateobj = dateobj[:19]
        arr2.append(int(datetime.datetime.strptime(dateobj, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())*1000)
        print('convert_datetime ',arr2[-1])
        #print('dateobj:', dateobj)
    return arr2
```

display_graphs/graphs.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'display_graphs/style.css' %}">
    <title>Display graphs page</title>
    <style>
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
          float: left;
        }

        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
        }

        .active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
        }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax5" align="center">
          <h1 style="background-color:white;align:center;color:red;padding:20px;width:50%;">Graph Page</h1>
              <p style="background-color:white;align:center;color:black;padding:50px;width:70%;">
                  Graphs are displayed below:</p><br>
                  <div id="container"></div>
                    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
                      <script>
                        Highcharts.chart('container', {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'scatter',
                                zoomtype:'xy'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Sell prices over time'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'price'
                                },
                                type: 'datetime',
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'end date'
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                data: x_v
                            }, {
                                data: y_v
                            }]
                        });
                      </script>

                  {% autoescape off %}
                      {{ response }}                    
                  {% endautoescape %}

              <br>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A sample date from the query is: 2019-09-30 23:11:17+00:00
The corresponding value changed into milliseconds since epoch: 1569899477000

According to all the docs and websites I've seen, the chart should be displaying and it's not. I can't figure out why. If you need more information and want to see the code so far, then here is a link to the github repo: [github repo link](https://github.com/IUS-CS/project-ordo_ab_chao)
I would like to point out that I have checked all the values, data types and counts of values for the x-axis and y-axis. The count of both python lists is 100. The data type of the x-axis (all float values) are floats. The data type of the y-axis are all int's as epoch milliseconds (converted from timestamps of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). Nothing in the data for both lists looks wrong. I've checked this manually on the command line. I just cannot figure out why the chart won't display. It theoretically should. I've spent around 8+ hours on this one problem. It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to display the chart on my django template.
mistake one: I had to change my prices (floats) from strings to floats data types.
mistake two: I was passing the floats (sell prices) to the x-axis, instead of the y-axis. I had the axes mixed up.
mistake three: I had to zip the two lists together as (x,y) pairs. An list of arrays with two elements. This makes one series. The first element in the array is the x value and the second value the y value.

THE FIX: I had to pass the data to the django template in the context to a variable in the chart script section. Code segment is below:

```
<div id="container"></div>
                    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                      <script>
                        chart1 = {{ chart1|safe }};
                        Highcharts.chart('container', {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'spline'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Sell prices over time'
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                type: 'datetime',
                                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                    month: '%e. %b',
                                    year: '%b'
                                },
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Date'
                                }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'price'
                                },
                                min: 0
                            },
                            series: [{
                                data: chart1
                            }]
                        });
                      </script>
```

The code segment of significance is this:

```
chart1 = {{ chart1|safe }};
```

Here is the code from my corresponding views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
import xmltodict
from json import loads, dumps
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from django.http import HttpResponse

content_df = pd.DataFrame()

def display_the_graphs(request):
    keywords = request.POST.get('search')
    api = finding(appid='JohnHein-homepage-PRD-392e94856-07aba7fe', config_file=None, siteid='EBAY-US')
    api_request = {'keywords':keywords, 'itemFilter':[{'name':'SoldItemsOnly', 'value':True},]}
    response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', api_request)
    content = response.content
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(content)
    content_dict = to_dict(xml_dict)
    count = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['@count']
    item_dict = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['item']
    print('count:', count)
    content_df = extract_values(item_dict)
    y_values = content_df['endPrice'].tolist()
    y_values = [float(i) for i in y_values]
    x_values_b = content_df['endTime'].tolist()
    x_values = convert_datetime(x_values_b)
    print('\nx_values: ', x_values,'\n')
    print('\ny_values: ', y_values,'\n')
    print('\nx_values count:', len(x_values),'\n')
    print('\ny_values count:', len(y_values),'\n')
    print('\nx_values type:', type(x_values[-1]),'\n')
    print('\ny_values type:', type(y_values[-1]),'\n')
    chart1_data = list(zip(x_values, y_values))
    print('chart1 data:', chart1_data)
    context = {
        'response': content_df.to_html(),
        'content_df': content_df,
        'chart1': chart1_data
    }
    return render(request, 'display_graphs/graphs.html', context)
'''
def get_time_graph(request):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title('Scatter plot of prices over time')
    ax.set_xlabel('dates')
    ax.set_ylabel('sell prices')
    ax.scatter(content_df.endDate.values, content_df.endPrice.values, s=10, label='sell prices over time')
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    context = {'first_graph':response}
    return render(request, 'display_graphs/graphs.html', context)
'''
def to_dict(input_ordered_dict):
    return loads(dumps(input_ordered_dict))

def extract_values(temp_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['itemId','title','endPrice','location','endTime'])
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []
    f = []
    #print('\ntype of data:\n', type(temp_dict))
    length = len(temp_dict)
    print('\nlength:\n', length)
    for index in range(length):
        for key, value in temp_dict[index].items():
            print('temp_dict[index][key]:', key)
            if key == 'itemId':
                a.append(value)
            if key == 'title':
                b.append(value)
            if key == 'sellingStatus':
                c.append(temp_dict[index]['sellingStatus']['currentPrice']['#text'])
            if key == 'location':
                d.append(value)
            if key == 'listingInfo':
                f.append(temp_dict[index]['listingInfo']['endTime'])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'itemId':pd.Series(a),'title':pd.Series(b),'endPrice':pd.Series(c),'location':pd.Series(d),'endTime':pd.Series(f)})  
    #print('\ndf:\n', df)
    #print('\narray a:\n', a)
    #print('\narray b:\n', b)
    #print('\narray c:\n', c)
    #print('\narray d:\n', d)
    #print('\narray f:\n', f)
    df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endTime']) # datetime ISO 8601 format ---> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +HH:MM (NOTE: '+HH:MM' is UTC offset)
    df['endTimeOfDay'],df['endDate'] = df['endTime'].apply(lambda x:x.time()),df['endTime'].apply(lambda x:x.date())
    return df

def convert_datetime(arr):
    arr2 = []
    for i in arr:
        dateobj = str(i)
        dateobj = dateobj[:19]
        arr2.append(int(datetime.datetime.strptime(dateobj, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())*1000)
        #print('convert_datetime ',arr2[-1])
        #print('dateobj:', dateobj)
    return arr2
```